# does timestamp function consider daylight savings in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The TIMESTAMP() fucntion in bigquery takes in timezone parameter. Does it consider day light savings as well?

If there are references to specific daylight saving information, please point to the links as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes TIMESTAMP() considers daylight saving time. Since [TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp) converts a string, date, datetime expression to timestamp data type we can check on the [data type timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type).

> A TIMESTAMP object represents an absolute point in time, independent
> of any time zone or convention such as Daylight Savings Time with
> microsecond precision.

To better understand this, here is an example to with timezone to show the behavior of timestamp when there is daylight saving time. See [timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_zone_name) for more details.

> Consider this time as an example:
>
> 2014-09-27 12:30:00.45 America/Los_Angeles
>
> Note that not all time zone names are interchangeable even if they do
> happen to report the same time during a given part of the year. For
> example, America/Los_Angeles reports the same time as UTC-7:00 during
> Daylight Savings Time, but reports the same time as UTC-8:00 outside
> of Daylight Savings Time.

With this example, we can say that TIMESTAMP() considers daylight saving time.